# Meteor, the use of Future for sync call

Tags: meteor, future

I've got the following code that doesn't work properly, with or without Future. Am I implementing Future in the right way?

```
 getGiphy: function(key) {
 var future = new Future();
 var url = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?s=cat+"+key+"&api_key=849238";
  //synchronous GET
  var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {timeout:30000});
  if(result.statusCode==200) {
    var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
    console.log("response received.");
    future["return"](respJson);
  } else {
    console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
    var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
    throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
  }

  return future.wait();
}
```

I'm getting this:
'Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getGiphy''

Comment: `getGiphy` is a meteor.method right? you have something like `Meteor.method({getGiphy:function(){//all code here}})`

Comment: yes, getGiphy is the function above, on the server. I've updated code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you have to implement future in this way:

```
var future = new Future();
....
future.return(respJson);
....
future.throw(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
....
return future.wait();
```

Hope that will help.

EDIT:

You can do the Meteor.http call in this way:

```
try {
    return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?s=cat+"+key+"&api_key=849238", {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: The first way does the same as my code, which is delivering the result to the client and throwing an exception error. The way without using Future just throws an error.

Comment: Is it possible that calling a method from client to server doesn't return anything? I've got 'if error' in the callback, console.log statements in there don't work (this is on the client), only console log before method statement (on click) shows up. Terminal doesn't show anything neither.